# How to query from multiindex dataframe containing data and time as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Check this image of dataframe

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L37JZ.png]

I've posted the picture of dataframe I am working with, I want to pull out data from specific times of a certain date

I've tried

1. `stockdf.loc[("2015-01-01")].loc['09:17:00']`
2. `stockdf.loc[("2015-01-01","09:17:00"),:]`

Both do not work.

Comment: It seems like you have date, and time indices as string.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
stockdf.loc[("2015-01-01", "09:17:00")]
```

If they're dates:

```
stockdf.loc[(pd.to_datetime("2015-01-01").date(), pd.to_datetime("09:17:00").time())]
```

Comment: Dupe, second answer.

Comment: My indexes are already in date and time format, i tried the first one with date it works. But with date and time together like you said it doesnt.  Key error -' 09:17:00'

Comment: @jezrael Ok... .

Comment: second one doesn't work too